# Java UI markup alternative to HTML?

Tags: java, html, swing, markup

I'm trying to use Java to develop a piece of software, but I've run into the issue of UI elements parsing HTML beyond the way I want them to.

The Java JEditorPane seems to be only able to be marked up by HTML or something that is essentially HTML underneath. I want the user to be able to type and see HTML tags, not have them formatted into markup, but still have something like the tags colored red and standard text not.

Is there a method of marking up Java's UIs without HTML? (I don't mind using an extra library, but if it can be avoided that'd be great.)

Comment: I don't understand your question.  Are you asking for a UI component that does syntax highlighting?  If so, RSyntaxTextArea (http://fifesoft.com/rsyntaxtextarea/) might be suitable.  Or search the web for "Java syntax highlight component" as see what works for you.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used it, but [RSyntaxTextArea](http://fifesoft.com/rsyntaxtextarea/) seems to achieve what you want. The intro says

> RSyntaxTextArea is a syntax highlighting text component for Java
>   Swing.

and

> Syntax highlighting for over 30 programming languages

Example usage and source code at [github](https://github.com/bobbylight/RSyntaxTextArea).